# unordered_set Visual Studio C++ Slow

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2012

So I think there was a bad version of C++ where unordered_set was incredibly slow. This piece of code took **one minute** to execute:

```
int main() {
    unordered_set<int> blah;
    for (int i = 0; i < 1000000; ++i)
    {
        blah.insert(i);
    }
    cout << "done 2" << endl;
    return 0;
}
```

It took about 40 seconds to get to the output statement, then took another 20 seconds to deallocate the object. It's C# counterpart with 10 times the insertions executes in about a second:

```
static void Main(string[] args)
{
    HashSet<int> set = new HashSet<int>();
    for (int i = 0; i < 10000000; ++i)
    {
        set.Add(i);
    }
}
```

This caused my FacebookHackerCup solution to not run in time :(. How can this be fixed for someone using the visual studio C++ IDE? I don't know what version it runs via command line or how to upgrade it.

Comment: Turn off debugging and turn on optimizations.

Comment: Without debugging cuts it down to 20 seconds... That's nice. How can you turn on optimizations? Also, C# is still 200 times faster with debugging on.

Comment: A blah.reserve(1000000); would also help.

Comment: I'm just trying to get to the bottom of why c++ is orders of magnitude worse than c#. There are plenty of ways to make it slightly better but I was hoping there might be a definitive answer as to why unordered_set is so slow. Even setting the number of buckets to 1,000,000 it is still very slow.

Comment: When doing performance tests always build in release mode. Also turn on optimizations http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/k1ack8f1(v=vs.110).aspx

Comment: Arguing that it is a problem of C++ vs C# is too myopic. It's at its best a comparison of the compilers.

For your C# code, maybe the compiler is simply not doing anything. As for the C++ code, I changed to `cout << blah.size() << endl;` to make sure the compiler won't optimize it out. It ran in 0.1s compiled with g++.

Comment: I'm definitely not arguing it's a question of C++ vs. C#. I'm arguing it's a problem with Visual C++ through Microsoft Visual Studio. I had a friend run the exact same code in a mac with gcc (g++) and it completed in less than a second.

I few things that gvd has suggested have greatly helped though, see my answer. Thanks gvd!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

- Run **without** debugging
- Need to compile in **Release** mode
- Potentially need to turn on optimizations by going to project properties -> Configuration Properties -> C/C++ -> Optimization -> **Maximize Speed (/O2)**. Mine was already set for Release, not for Debug.

This makes the original code run in about a second, and the 10,000,000 variant to run in about 8 seconds (so still about ~4 times slower than C# in Debug mode with debugging). EDIT: It seems C#'s speed does not greatly change with or without debugging or building in Release mode for this particular program.